# Как преобразовать получаемую строку в hasmap или arrayList в Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-hashmap

Имеется `GET` запрос, после всех махинаций у меня получается одна большая строка с всей информацией. Как мне ее преобразовать в что то более структурированное типа `hasmap` или `arrayList`?

```
package ghibli;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String url = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films";
            URL obj = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
//                response.append("\n");
            }

            in.close();

//            System.out.println(response.toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", ""));
            
            
            String stringValuses = response.toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", "");
            System.out.println(stringValuses);


            Object objJson = JSONValue.parse(stringValuses);
//            System.out.println(stringValuses);

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) objJson;
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("title");
//            System.out.println(name);

//            Ghibli ghibli = new Ghibli();
//            ghibli.startApp();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ghibli.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

//     ghibli.getData("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films");
    }

}
```

Comment: Надо полагать, что ваша строка - JSON. Коли так, то возьмите любой парсер оного, Gson от богомерзкого гугла, например и распарсите ответ сервера в нужную вам структуру. Заодно можно взять связку Retrofit+Gson чтобы оно выглядело красивше и было удобнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем okhttp, gson, lombok, это все упростит. Получаем примерно следующее:

```
public class Main {
    
    private final static OkHttpClient HTTP_CLIENT = new OkHttpClient();
    private final static Gson GSON = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
                .get()
                .build();
        
        Response result = HTTP_CLIENT.newCall(request).execute();
        List<Model> models = GSON.fromJson(result.body().charStream(), List.class);
        System.out.println(models);
    }

}

@Data
class Model{
    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String original_title;
    public String original_title_romanised;
    public String description;
    public String director;
    public String producer;
    public String release_date;
    public String running_time;
    public String rt_score;
    public List<String> people;
    public List<String> species;
    public List<String> locations;
    public List<String> vehicles;
    public String url;
}
```

Comment: А как мне тогда дотянуться до id например. Если я циклом с начало прохожусь по всему List<Model>, а до конкретной пары ключ значения дотянуться не могу.

Comment: у вас по условиям задачи нужен List или Map. поскольку сериализатор не сможет преобразовать данные в Map, то в этом примере использован List . теперь все зависит от задачи, которая перед вами стоит. если вам действительно нужно искать быстро и только по id, то надо из List седлать Map. в противном случае любой элемент нужно искать простым перебором, это же List , тут иначе никак

Comment: по условию задачи мне не нужно искать быстро и только по id, я буду использовать все поля. Вот у меня и возникает вопрос, мол когда я перебрал list<model> простым циклом и могу дотянуться с помощью models.get(i) до конкретного объекта. Как мне в дальнейшем дотянуться до конкретного ключа и значения этого i-го обьекта.

Comment: какого ключа-значения? у вас здесь лист. здесь нет никакого ключа-значения. вы дошли итератором до объекта и получили все данные , которые хранятся в объекте. можно сделать map, где ключ будет айдишник, тогда будете получать объект методом get без всяких циклов